# Change paper-fab color using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

This snippet I used to change the style of an fab element before:

```
<style is="custom-style">
    :root {
        --paper-fab-background: #42a9f7 !important;
    }
</style>
```

But how can I change the color using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```
this.$.paperfab.updateStyles({ '--paper-fab-background': '#42a9f7' });
```

With paperfab being the id of your paper-fab element placed in a function, of course.

Comment: in fact, a lot of properties can be accessed this way.  this.$.mypaperfabid.title = "save button" can be used to change the hover text.

Answer (score 0):

Its Easy First set an Id to the html element whose color you want to change then use document.getElementById(elementID).style.backgroundColor = #42a9f7 !important; 
Thats It

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but changing the backgroundColor sadly dosen't work!

Answer (score 0):

Change color of an element via JavaScript:

Change element color:
`document.getElementById(elementID).style.color = "#42a9f7"`;

Multiple styles on element:
`document.getElementById(elementID).style.cssText = "color:#42a9f7;background:red"`;